# diffculty implementing EFCodeFirst.CreateTablesOnly / DontDropDbJustCreateTablesIfModelChangedStart

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, nuget

I'm having difficulty implementing EFCodeFirst.CreateTablesOnly (changed to DontDropDbJustCreateTablesIfModelChangedStart).

I have successfully pulled in the package using NUGET. Now there is a mention of

in packages.config

and a DontDropDbJustCreateTablesIfModelChangedStart.cs

I've added Devtalk.EF.CodeFirst to references

in my app_start directory.

But I still can't make use of the DontDropDbJustCreateTablesIfModelChangedStart class. When I do, the app dies with msg

> Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=4.1.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

When I check definition of DontDropDbJustCreateTablesIfModelChangedStart, I find it only has a signature and not a definition.

What did I do wrong? Or what step did I leave out? Am I supposed to Implement the Class/Method?

Comment: Start with the error message. What does it say to you? There is some problem with loading assembly. Do you reference the assembly? Is it available in your web application? Are you using correct version?

Comment: Ladislav, if I use the default method for SetInitializer (CreateDatabaseIfNotExists), there is no error. So, Entity Framework is loading correctly. My problem is with the DontDropDbJustCreateTablesIfModelChangedStart. I DO have a reference to this dll Devtalk.EF.Codefirst

Does this help?

Comment: No it doesn't help. What version of EF are you using exactly? If you use default initializer you are using "some" version. The error says there is a problem loading version 4.1.0.0 or some dependency.

Comment: I understand. Using EF 4.3. Code-First.

Comment: i swapped this text in the global.asax


            //System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<CustomerOrders.Models.CustomerOrdersDB>());

            System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new DontDropDbJustCreateTablesIfModelChanged<CustomerOrders.Models.CustomerOrdersDB>());


EFCodeFirst.CreateTablesOnly   1.0.2 is also loaded

Comment: I see your point, Ladislav. In truth, I just upgraded (nuget) EF 4.3, when I was previously running 4.1. And this seems to be more the issue. Oddly, though, my comp reference and pointer in web.config use System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.3.0.0. Some how this is my real problem.

Comment: Thanks again Ladislav. You pointed me to focus on the error regarding version number instead of the red-herring of having installed EFCodeFirst.CreateTablesOnly incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that library was probably compiled with EntityFramework.dll version 4.1.0.0 and author didn't update it for version 4.2.0.0 and 4.3.0.0. Try to [redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19.aspx) version 4.1.0.0 to version 4.3.0.0 in your web.config file.

Comment: I agree, but is confusing. web.config points to EF 4.3. In fact, I can't find any reference to EF 4.1.

Comment: The reference is not in your code. The reference is in the code you are referencing.

Comment: very perceptive. it was the EFCodeFirst.CreateTablesOnly insisting on using EF 4.1.

Answer (score 1):

Don't Use it use EF's Migrations:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-released.aspx

Comment: It's been 6months but I just got a chance to read your post. Very good stuff. But I feel like EF deserves more robust deployment support. Any serious efforts planned in this direction?